# simple for loop in coffee script not working

Tags: coffeescript

This is probably a question with a very simple answer but I am just not able to grasp why this is not working;

```
sort = (arr) ->
    word for word in arr
        if word is 'some word'
                console.log 'word present'
```

All I want to do is to console.log is a word is present in the array but I am just getting

```
Parse error on line 4: Unexpected 'INDENT'
```

Could somebody please explain or give me a hint to why this is not working.
Thanks :)

Comment: I think there is definitely white space issue

Comment: @The-Val no it isn't the problem is with the loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code should look like this. (Look closely to the loop):

```
sort = (arr) ->
    for word in arr
        if word is 'some word'
            console.log 'word present'
```

or shorthand:

```
sort = (arr) ->
    for word in arr when word is 'some word'
        console.log 'word present'
```

The syntax you tried to use is for comprehension.

Here an example where you could save the first letter of every element of the array that matches:

```
sort = (arr) ->
    firstLetter = (word[0] for word in arr when word is 'some word')
```

**EDIT:**
Combine the examples from above:

```
sort = (arr) ->
    console.log word for word in arr when word is 'some word'
```

Comment: Note: I always find it helpful to use the "Try coffeescript" option on the coffeescript home page. It gives you a fast insight what actually is happening.

Comment: Thanks! New to coffee but your answer helped!

Comment: @miner Glad I could help. CoffeeScript is awesome, but it takes a little bit to really get to know it.